# How to check SqLite database file and get my defined database user-version?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app that using sq-lite database. in my app when user tap on backup my sq-lite db file save on another place. i now write a new version of my app and in new version my sq-lite db has some more fields. how can i check sq-lite database file and get user-version of that file to open it with true fields avoiding force-close?
in new version off my app the db version is 2:

```
private final static String DB_NAME="cDb";
private final static String DB_TABLE="_table";
private final static int DB_VERSION=2;
```

But in old version my db version is 1.
How can i check if my db file is for version 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getVersion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion%28%29) to get database version , but anyway just to let you know as soon as you open your database if its an old one [onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) should be triggered.

Comment: how can i get my db file version in onUpgrade? when i use getVersion() it returns the new version to me that i defined before on my SQLiteOpenHelper constractor:

Comment: take a look at onUpgrade parameters , you have oldVersion and newVersion

Answer (score 2):

Use `PRAGMA user_version` sql to get database version

Comment: @aTa , you must be connected to the device using adb, this link has it all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap sqlite (cordova-sqlite-storage plugin), you can get user_version as :

```
db.executeSql('PRAGMA user_version', [], migrate, function(){console.log('unable to fetch user_version');});

function migrate(db, resultSet {console.log(resultSet.rows.item(0).user_version);}
```