# SQLite Database storage in /data/data Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one sqlite database stored in an "assets" folder and I'd like to store it into /data/data folder within the Android device. It's just a readonly db from which I want to retrieve data.

I've been reading a lot of topics talking about that but when I check the /data/data/ folder in my device, my package isn't there. Here's the code I've been using:

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "DataBaseManager";

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.my_package/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "my_database";
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseManager(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        Log.d("DATABASE", "ALREADY EXIST");
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.d("DATABASE", "DOESNT EXIST");
    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    Log.d("COPY DATABASE", "DATABASE COPIED");
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM chapters", null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        cursor.getString(3);
        Log.d("CONTENT", cursor.getString(3));
    }

    myDataBase.beginTransaction();
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Thanks to the Log.d() messages, I can see the following message : "database already exists" (message from createDatabase method) and yet, I have no data in the /data/data folder of my Android device.

This seems strange to me because in checkDatabase method, I check if a database exists in myPath variable, variable whose value corresponds to DB_PATH and DB_NAME, namely the /data/data folder and, like I said, I opened the internal memory of my device and checked if something was created in the /data/data folder but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you hav to change the DB_NAME variable from "my_database" to "my_database.sqlite"

and u cant see your database on your internal memory... bcoz the database will save only to the system folder...
if u want to check it u might need a rooted android device or you can check using android studio...

check this link... [check database if exist in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24809016/4707780)

Comment: Indeed, that's what I've done. I used the "CREATE_IF_NECESSARY" flag and added the ".sqlite" extension. Now I can even retrieve data from this database . But, I still have a question, if I want to create my folder not into /data/data but in the same folder where "data" or "Download" folder is (some applications create their folder there). How can I do that? Just changing the db_path by "/my_package_name" (doesn't seem to work, I have an error when I try)?

Thanks for your message!

Comment: thats what i am saying man... in your current code, the database is stored in the android system folder, which is not accessible by a normal user...you hav to root your device and use a file explorer liek root explorer to view the files...   and if you want to store your database in internal memory or memorycard, do this in database helper context... DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Better to check `DB File` like

```
 public boolean checkDataBase(){
    File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return databaseFile.exists();        
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and nothing changed. It acts like the DB already exists in this folder but oddly, I don't see it.

I also try to change the db_path ("/data/data/com.my_package"), still with this code of yours and now, it calls copyDatabase method but the code throws the error message "error copying database".

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase`will automatically create the DB if it doesn't exists (see `CREATE_IF_NECESSARY`flag).

In general, you must first copy the embedded databse from asset directory to your application data directory : `data/data/com.my_package/databases`.

Then you can use your database.

See SQLiteAssetHelper if necessary: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper