# Android: View app private data - debugging

Tags: android, debugging, adb, remote-debugging, stetho

Is there any nice tool out there that helps with debugging by providing a way to browse through private files of an app?

The only way I found so far is by [rooting the device and using Device Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db).

[image]

I am assuming there must be library out there to make it easier. I tried Stetho from Facebook, but unfortunately they only provide access to Shared-Pref files and they don't provide a tool to browse directories and files.

If I come to a conclusion that there is absolutely no library for such purpose, I'll write one and post here :)

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) provided by Facebook you can try out.It not only allows you to see the sharedpreferences but your database also.Not even this ,it helps you query your databases modifying it and lot more.You can do these operations with your sharedPreferences as well.
Stetho helps you to see your network calls and display the UI elements of your Android UI and you can change the values of the text vies and  see it  getting affected in the UI while your app is running. 
There are few more tutorial you should check out for understanding Stetho

[Tutorial 1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/debugging-android-apps-with-facebooks-stetho--cms-24205)

[Sample app from Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho)

Comment: I am familiar with Stetho, its capabilities are limited to SharedPref and SQLite, you cannot view raw files within your app's folder.