# Android export SQLite Database to Computer / Mac

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database on my Android Device (My own App). Now i want to see the SQLite Database on my Computer.

Is there any solution ( easy way ) to get the Database without root rights and without a SD-Card on my Computer?

I tried to google it but i can't find any solution for this problem....

Edit: I'm using not the Emulator ( need the Camera on my Device).

Comment: In my opinion there is no way for a non rooted device to get sqlite database from.

Comment: The easiest way is through Terminal, the complete guide in this link . answer by dheeraj bhaskar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method worked for my unrooted device.

```
# check if your device connected
adb devices

adb shell

run-as  your.package.name

chmod 777 databases/your.database.name

exit

cp /data/data/your.package.name/your.database.name /mnt/sdcard/

exit

adb pull /mnt/sdcard/your.database.name
```

Comment: copy to file folder to accessible to you.
 do adb shell. cd mnt/ Then ls. And tell me the folder names. I will tell you where to copy the database

Comment: the folder name on my Computer?

Comment: No, folder on your device. Do adb shell, and cd mnt and then ls (it L for london) and tell me the result.

Comment: Oh okay. I Thought it was a Upper i. I Tell You later, because i'm on work :D

Comment: i used the cat command. cp doesn't work. cat /data/data/your.package.name/databases/database.name >/mnt/sdcard/database.sqlite

Comment: So could you do it. Was it successful?

Comment: Ist was successful but Not with the "cp" command. I used the "cat" command. Thank you

Comment: when trying to copy the DB to mnt/sdcard it says `permission denied`

Comment: Still getting **permission denied** error

Answer (score 6):

if phone is not rooted you cant access directly your DB, but you can copy it to download folder, then, copy to PC

```
public static void copyAppDbToDownloadFolder(Activity ctx) throws IOException {
    File backupDB = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            "databse_name.db"); // for example "my_data_backup.db"
    File currentDB = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("databasename.db");
    if (currentDB.exists()) {
        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
        src.close();
        dst.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try it later. If this works, you'll get a +vote

Comment: @FunkyMan you can't upvote, yet. But you can mark this answer as accepted. I guess you must wait a couple of days, though.

Comment: facing EAaccess permission denied issue not able to copy

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving Sqlite DB in default location , you can find the same in path like following

```
/data/data/com.dev.myapplication/databases/mydb.db
```

You can find the same using Android Device Monitor, through which you can navigate to both internal and external memory.

Once you find the database file, extract the same and save in desktop after connecting through USB cable. You can use option "Pull a file from device"

[image]

Once you have extracted file to desktop, use any tools similar to [Mozilla Firefox SQLite viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to view database.

Comment: But i need Root rights to get this Database, or not? I've tried this but my "data" folder is empty.

Comment: No root rights is required for this. Try to save to some other location and verify. For example your external SD card location and some custom folders.

Comment: I don't have a SD card...I try to save it to a other location. Thanks.

Comment: /data/data is not an accessible directory