# In my adb shell ,in the databases, when I enter "select * from Book",it becomes this

Tags: android

[image]

In my `adb shell`, in the databases, when I enter:

```
select * from Book
```

Becomes this.

Comment: why it becomes ....>?

Comment: You must end statement lines with semi colon `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not selected the database. Use the command -> CD your_db_name to select your database then Use,

SELECT * FROM book;

A query normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a semicolon. (There are some exceptions where a semicolon may be omitted. QUIT, mentioned earlier, is one of them. We'll get to others later.)

[Access database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db)

Comment: Thanks , I forget add a ";" in the end .