# Unable to access SQLite db file in android studio device monitor api 23 and above

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am unable to view SQLite db file in android studio device monitor from android-studio>tools>android>Android-Device-Monitor. I am using an API 25(android 7.1) image for my emulator, heard that I cannot do this from android 6.0 and above. Is this true? Or is there any other way to access that file in studio. (Currently I am unable to click on "data" folder in Device Monitor(DDMS). When I click on data, it shows nothing in it, though database is created and insertion is performing.)

Comment: Try this https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue at Uni. I decided to use the command line to ssh into the emulator and run sqlite commands to view what I needed. This is detailed on stackoverflow here [How to use ADB in Android Studio to view an SQLite DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db)

Comment: Thanks @Neil but I need a direct gui based way for my purpose, can you still help?