# Android Sqlite database is not updating the data??

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using this code to update the values

this Code is working properly without an error there is no error in query but when i show data after updating its showing the old data??

this is the code i am using for updating the data in sqlite.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == Update) {
            try {
                ContentValues CV = new ContentValues();
                CV.put("cname", EditName.getText().toString());
                CV.put("mobileno", EditMobile.getText().toString());
                CV.put("phone", EditLandline.getText().toString());
                CV.put("address", EditAddress.getText().toString());
                CV.put("email", EditEmail.getText().toString());
                CV.put("picture", Editbytes);
                DB.update("contacts", CV, "cname=" + V,null);

                Intent I = new Intent(ctx, ContactList.class);
                ctx.startActivity(I);


                // DB.execSQL("insert into contacts values('" + Name.getText() + "','" + Mobile.getText() + "','" + Phone.getText() + "','" + Add.getText() + "','" + Email.getText() + "')");
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Contact Updated...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Fail to Update Contact.." + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        } else if (v == Delete) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Update your database version may solve the problem

Comment: Please add more information like SQLite version, DB configuration, etc.

Comment: Please add full file listing and list of gradle dependencies. If `DB` class is also yours, add its listing as well.

Comment: i am using 1.12.0 sqlite version

Comment: DB is not a class its the SqliteDatabase variable

Comment: What is `V`? What is its value?

Comment: V is a string , and i have also tried it by using id but that is also not working

Comment: i got my issue resolved now my code is working properly, and  thank you everbody for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this,

```
DB.update("contacts", CV, "cname=" + V,null);
```

What is the V, is that particular name , I thingk, you may try to udapte using id, which is more effective.

Change to

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.update("contacts", CV, "cid=" + "=" + id, null);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

However, if you don't update, please clean your project and rebuild, that might work.If this will not help, please post you logcat.

Comment: V is a string , and i have also tried it by using id but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance WHERE clause is not matching any rows?

You can test your condition on console with:

`Log.i(db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cname=" + V));`

But I think the best way to test this is connect directly to database:

- Open a terminal on Android Studio (View > Tool Windows > Terminal)
- Enter `adb shell` (if command fails, add your `adb` installation into PATH variable)
- The database file is usually stored in `/data/data/com.your.package/database/`
- Run `sqlite3 /data/data/com.your.package/database/YourAPP.db` to open a prompt where you can run all SQL commands

[Another good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206366/8441814)