# how to get sqlite database with adb commands?

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

A few months ago, I've developed a windows application to get my android application sqlite database with this adb command :
adb exec-out run-as mypackagename cat /databases/mydbname.db > myPCaddress(D:\mydbname.db)

It was working correctly but after a while when I want to test it again, the command copy a file in the PC, which has 1kb size and not even a database file! I'm so confused and I don't know what is the problem.Please help me.

Comment: Try out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db

Comment: I don't want to root my device

Answer (score 0):

1. `adb exec-out run-as` works only with debug builds
2. Easy way to view the inner db: http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ super easy integration - just add it to your `build.gradle`