# xamarin forms sqlite-net-pcl table not in db3 file

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, sqlite-net-pcl

I am trying to make a cross platform app using a local sqlite db and I got the plumming for IOS and Android set up.

I get to the point where I can get the db using "adb.exe and pull". I use DB browser for Sqlite to view the db file. The file has no tables.

But when I look into the SQLiteConnection in the code I can see the tables and if I query I get data.

Any ideas?

-- update

maybe I shoud mention. I am using Visual Studio with Xamarin forms and sqlite-net-pcl

Answer (score 0):

I think the table exist in the db since you can query data from the table.
Could you try to use another tool to view the DB file instead of DB browser?

And make sure the db you open is the correct one.

Here is a link that might help you:
[How to use ADB in Android Studio to view an SQLite DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370219/how-to-use-adb-in-android-studio-to-view-an-sqlite-db)

Comment: Hi jack. thx for your post. I´m sure it´s the correct one, as the connection is snatched directly from the AVD monitor.